# How to activate multiple devices with differing Mac addresses in one python code?

Tags: python, function, initialization, system, input-devices

I am trying to make a code more efficient by making python code activate multiple devices at once. Currently, this code is being used to run 5 of the same devices, same instructions, but the script is being run separately for each device. The code starts out with `system_init()` and is connected to a Mac address, but I wanted to know if it was possible to define the `system_init()` function with these devices and their Mac addresses to run them all simultaneously? This code is currently being run in Fenics dolfin.
I am unsure how the devices are connected to the computer system, I am pretty sure it is by some physical port and not bluetooth.
An example of the code I am envisioning looks something like this:

```py
def system_init():
    # Define a list of device configurations including device names and MAC addresses
    device_configs = [
        {'device_name': 'Device1', 'mac_address': '00:11:22:33:44:55'},
        {'device_name': 'Device2', 'mac_address': '11:22:33:44:55:66'},
        # Add more devices with their respective MAC addresses
    ]

    # Initialize devices with their known MAC addresses
    for config in device_configs:
        device_name = config['device_name']
        mac_address = config['mac_address']
        
        # Configure the device with its known MAC address
        configure_device_mac(device_name, mac_address)

def configure_device_mac(device_name, mac_address):
    # Use platform-specific code to configure the network interface
    # with the known MAC address for the specified device
    # The exact implementation will depend on the platform and programming language used
```

**# Call the initialization routine to set up devices with known MAC addresses**
system_init()

The spot where I am a little confused lies in the "def configure_device_mac(device_name, mac_address):
# Use platform-specific code to configure the network interface
# with the known MAC address for the specified device
# The exact implementation will depend on the platform and programming language used" piece of this proposed code. What lines of code do I need to add after this def function?

After this first function is coded, the rest of the script goes into defining some variables and then def main().

Does this proposal seem like it could work? The Mac addresses of each device that will be run are readily available to me. Will I need to identify how the systems are connected to the computer? If so, how can I tell what kind of connection it is and what code to add?
Thanks.

This is just a proposed code, I have not tested it yet.